# Update a list of data in the database

Tags: c#

```
public ActionResult Event_History(int id = 0)
    {
        //set into false the active flag of the event
        Events_Info_tbl events = db.Events_Info_tbl.Find(id);
        events.is_active = false;
        db.Entry(events).State = EntityState.Modified;

        //set the category under this event into inactive
        List<Events_Category_tbl> category = new List<Events_Category_tbl>();
        category = db.Events_Category_tbl.Where(x=>x.events_info_id==id).ToList();          
        foreach(var i in category){
            Events_Category_tbl cat = new Events_Category_tbl();
            cat.is_active = false;
            db.Entry(cat).State = EntityState.Modified; 
        }

        db.SaveChanges();

        TempData["MessageAlert"] = "Event is save in history!";

        return RedirectToAction("Index");


    }
```

Iam planning to set into inactive all the category belongs to that particular event but when I try to run this code an error displayed "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key." pointing to this part of my code `db.Entry(cat).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: You don't need to change the state manually, it's handle by EF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code try to create new object and save in DB, and all new object has same Id that's why give that error:

```
Events_Category_tbl cat = new Events_Category_tbl();
cat.is_active = false;
db.Entry(cat).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

You don't need to create new object, just update the retrieved entity:

```
public ActionResult Event_History(int id = 0)
{
    //set into false the active flag of the event
    var events = db.Events_Info_tbl.Find(id);
    events.is_active = false;        

    //set the category under this event into inactive
    var category = db.Events_Category_tbl.Where(x=>x.events_info_id==id).ToList();          
    foreach(var cat in category){
        cat.is_active = false;
    }

    db.SaveChanges();

    TempData["MessageAlert"] = "Event is save in history!";

    return RedirectToAction("Index");


}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     foreach(var i in category){
        Events_Category_tbl cat = new Events_Category_tbl();
        cat.is_active = false;
        db.Entry(cat).State = EntityState.Modified; 
    }
```

This part does not make any sense. You should not create a new instance of Events_Category_tbl.

You should instead just

```
    foreach(var i in category){
        i.is_active = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

categories in a table may repeat themselves.... please replace:

```
db.Events_Category_tbl.Where(x=>x.events_info_id==id).ToList()
```

with

```
db.Events_Category_tbl.Where(x=>x.events_info_id==id).Distinct().ToList()
```

THAT WAY YOU WILL MAKE SURE THAT EVERY ITEM REPEAT ONLY ONCE